# Is a planar square on the equator a locally energy minimizing configuration of electrons on $\mathbb{S}^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, optimization, maxima-minima, symmetry

$\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}^2}$Let$$M=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in  \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^2 \, |\,\, \text{ all the } x_i \, \text{ are distinct}\} $$

Let $E:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$E(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\sum_{i < j}\frac{1}{\| x_i - x_j \|},$$

where $\| x_i - x_j \|$ denotes the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Question:** Let $p:=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ be the configuration of a planar square lying on the equator of $\S$. Is $p$ a *local minimum* of $E$?

(Of course, it is not a strict minima since one can rotate).

---

**Here is an attempt:**

Let $\beta_i(t)$ be a path in $\mathbb{S}^2$, $\beta_i(0)=x_i, \dot \beta(0)=w_i \in T_{x_i}\S$.

Consider the path $$\alpha(t)=(\beta_1(t),\beta_2(t),\beta_3(t),\beta_4(t)).$$
Using
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dt}| \beta_i(t) - \beta_j(t) |^{-1}=\frac{d}{dt}(| \beta_i(t) - \beta_j(t) |^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\&=| \beta_i(t) - \beta_j(t)  |^{-3}\big(\langle \dot \beta_i(t), \beta_j(t)\rangle+\langle \beta_i(t), \dot \beta_j(t)\rangle\big), \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(\alpha(t))=\sum_{i<j}| \beta_i(t) - \beta_j(t)  |^{-3}\big(\langle \dot \beta_i(t), \beta_j(t)\rangle+\langle \beta_i(t), \dot \beta_j(t)\rangle\big). \tag{2}
$$
In particular, denoting the length of the square's edge by $a$, and assuming that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the square's vertices *arranged in a cyclic order* we have
$$
dE_p(0,0,0,w)=\sum_{i=1}^3 | x_i - x_4 |^{-3}\langle x_i,w\rangle=a^{-3}  \langle x_1+x_3,w\rangle+(a\sqrt 2)^{-3}
\langle x_2,w \rangle=0,
$$
where we used the fact that $x_3=-x_1$, and $x_2=-x_4$, so $\langle x_2,w \rangle=-\langle x_4,w \rangle=0$ as $w \in T_{x_4}\S$.

---

Differentiating equation $(2)$ again, we get
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}| \beta_i - \beta_j |^{-1}=| \beta_i - \beta_j |^{-3}\bigg(3| \beta_i - \beta_j |^{-2}\big(\langle \dot \beta_i, \beta_j\rangle+\langle \beta_i, \dot \beta_j\rangle\big)^2+\langle \ddot \beta_i, \beta_j\rangle+\langle \beta_i, \ddot \beta_j\rangle+2 \langle \dot\beta_i, \dot \beta_j\rangle\bigg)\tag{2}.
$$
Now, consider first all the $i<j$ such that $j=i+1 \text{mod} 4$, i.e. $i-j$ is an edge of the square, or equivalently $d_{ij}=|x_i-x_j|=a$.

If we choose e.g. $j=4$, then the two neighbors are $i=1,3$, and so combining terms $1-4,3-4$ we get
$$
\langle x_1+x_3, \ddot \beta_4(0)\rangle=0,
$$
and similarly for the other two edges $1-2,2-3$.
Thus
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}E(\alpha(t))=a^{-3}\bigg( 3a^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^4\big(\langle x_i,\dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+\langle x_{i+1},\dot \beta_{i}\rangle\big)^2  +2\langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle\bigg)+A,
$$
where $A$ is the part correspondong to $i-j$ equal $1-3$, $2-4$ (the diagonals).

*Consider the pair $2-4$:*

$\langle x_2,\dot \beta_{4}\rangle=-\langle x_4,\dot \beta_{4}\rangle=0$, so the first summand $3(a\sqrt 2)^{-2}...$ vanishes.

Thus we are left with
$$A=(a\sqrt 2)^{-3}\bigg( \langle \ddot \beta_2, \beta_4\rangle+\langle \beta_2, \ddot \beta_4\rangle+2 \langle \dot\beta_2, \dot \beta_4\rangle \bigg).
$$
Since
$$
\langle \ddot \beta_2, \beta_4\rangle=-\langle \ddot \beta_2, \beta_2\rangle=|\dot \beta_2|^2,
$$
we get
$$
A=(a\sqrt 2)^{-3}\bigg( |\dot \beta_2+\dot \beta_4|^2+ |\dot \beta_1+\dot \beta_3|^2 \bigg).
$$
Thus, up to a factor of $a^{-3}$, we have
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}E(\alpha(t))=3a^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^4\big(\langle x_i,\dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+\langle x_{i+1},\dot \beta_{i}\rangle\big)^2  +2\langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+
$$
$$
\sqrt 2^{-3}\bigg( |\dot \beta_2+\dot \beta_4|^2+ |\dot \beta_1+\dot \beta_3|^2 \bigg).
$$

Since $a=\sqrt 2$, we get
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}E(\alpha(t))=3/2\sum_{i=1}^4\big(\langle x_i,\dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+\langle x_{i+1},\dot \beta_{i}\rangle\big)^2  +2\langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+
$$
$$
\sqrt 2^{-3}\bigg( |\dot \beta_2+\dot \beta_4|^2+ |\dot \beta_1+\dot \beta_3|^2 \bigg).
$$

Is the last quantity $\ge 0$?

(If I am not mistaken in my computations so far...).

Comment: I haven't checked your work. I suspect the four vertices of a regular tetrahedron do better globally but that is probably a local extreme point.

Comment: If you think of the electrons as arranged along the equator or the sphere, try moving one opposite pair toward the north pole and the other opposite pair toward the south pole, all at equal speeds. This variation should decrease the energy at second order, and isn't too difficult to compute.

Comment: @AsafShachar One simple way to see it is a symmetry argument: Focusing on a single charge $q\in S^2$, the configuration has two orthogonal mirror symmetries which fix $q$. The force (i.e. the derivative of $E$ w.r.t. the location of the charge at $q$) must be invariant under these symmetries, and so it must vanish.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks, that sounds like a very elegant argument! However, I am missing two things: (1) I see only *one* diagonal reflection (in $D_4$) that fixes say $x_1$, where $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ form a square in a cyclic order. That is, the reflection map fixes $x_1,x_3$ and swaps $x_2,x_4$. So, where is the other mirror symmetry coming from? (2) Denoting by $L$ this reflection, this induces a map $A:(\mathbb{S}^2)^4 \to (\mathbb{S}^2)^4$, where $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=( L(x_1),L(x_2),L(x_3),L(x_4) )=(x_1,x_4,x_3,x_2)$. Thus we have $E \circ A=E$, which implies

Comment: $dE_{A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)} \circ A=dE_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}$ or $dE_{(x_1,x_4,x_3,x_2)} \circ A=dE_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}$. So, this relates the gradient of $E$ at two *different* points  $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4), (x_1,x_4,x_3,x_2)$. I guess that to proceed you intended to use the fact that the permutation of coordinates $x_2 \iff x_4$ is also a symmetry? Or did I miss something? (If you prefer, then I can ask a separate question on this symmetry argument, which I find fascinating).

Comment: @AsafShachar By *symmetry* I mean a Euclidean transformation of the ambient space that does not alter the distribution of charge. One is the reflection you describe; the other mirror symmetry is the reflection across the equatorial plane. It doesn't move any of the charges, but it acts nontrivially on $T_qS^2$

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks! I think I got it now. That is a really clever, nice argument. I do think that to write formally the part of the reflection along the diagonal, you need to use the rather trivial observation that $E$ is invariant under permutations of the components in the product of spheres. (as I mentioned above, the reflection formally moves us to a "different but essentially identical" configuration). I have spelled out the details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4456338/104576 . You may see in particular the second part, beginning in "The idea in a nutshell:".

Comment: Is my argument there what you have intended? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the answer is negative.

The variation that moves one opposite pair toward the north pole and the other opposite pair toward the south pole, all at equal speeds, decreases the energy at second order.

Indeed, we take
$$
x_1=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0), x_2=(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0), x_3=(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0),x_4=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0),
$$
then the given variation corresponds to
$$
\dot \beta_1=\dot \beta_3=(0,0,-1),\dot \beta_2=\dot \beta_4=(0,0,1).
$$
Then the formula
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}E(\alpha(t))=3/2\sum_{i=1}^4\big(\langle x_i,\dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+\langle x_{i+1},\dot \beta_{i}\rangle\big)^2  +2\langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+
$$
$$
\sqrt 2^{-3}\bigg( |\dot \beta_2+\dot \beta_4|^2+ |\dot \beta_1+\dot \beta_3|^2 \bigg),
$$
gives in this situation
$$
2 \sum_{i=1}^4 \langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle+\sqrt 2^{-3}(4+4).
$$
Since all $\langle \dot \beta_{i}, \dot \beta_{i+1}\rangle=-1$, we obtain
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}|_{t=0}E(\alpha(t))=8(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2^{3}}-1)<0
$$
as required.